# How do I insert the formula into the cell when the formula keeps changing with an increase in row?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003, excel-formula

I have entered these formula in the second row of the Pth column:

```
=(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A2)=0)+(COUNTIF(B$1:B1,B2)=0)+(COUNTIF(F$1:F1,F2)=0)
```

When I drag it to the third row of the Pth column, it gets like this:

```
 =(COUNTIF(A$1:A2,A3)=0)+(COUNTIF(B$1:B2,B3)=0)+(COUNTIF(F$1:F2,F3)=0)
```

This is what I do manually. How do I make it using VBA? I have tried in the way below.

```
cells(Count,"M").formula= "=(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A2)=0)+(COUNTIF(B$1:B1,B2)=0)+(COUNTIF(F$1:F1,F2)=0)"
```

But it's not working. It's not changing from

```
"=(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A2)=0)+(COUNTIF(B$1:B1,B2)=0)+(COUNTIF(F$1:F1,F2)=0)"
```

to

```
"=(COUNTIF(A$1:A2,A3)=0)+(COUNTIF(B$1:B2,B3)=0)+(COUNTIF(F$1:F2,F3)=0)"
```

How do I insert the formula into the cell when the formula keeps changing with an increase in row?

Comment: You could copy/paste the formula directly in VBA; instead of setting the formula to a text value, copy it from a cell in which it's correct, and paste in the target cell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this in one line:

```
range("P2").Copy Destination:=range("P3:P10")
```

No need for variables, loops, anything!

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Joubarc

```
Cells(2, "P").Copy
For Row = 3 To 10
     Cells(Row, "P").Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste
 Next Row
```

Comment: you don't need to select the cells to copy `Cells(2, "P").Copy` should work

Comment: Good point.  Changed select and then copy to direct cell copy.

Comment: +1 for helpful answer. You can do this in 1 line, though (I posted my solution).