# Insert COUNTIF formula when you have variable holding the value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003, excel-formula

Consider:

```
 Cells(2, "Q").Formula = "=COUNTIF(P$1:P1,P2)=0"
```

How do I insert these formulae when I have a variable holding a value?

I have to start the formula at 3550 row and 4000 row somtimes. It depends on the data. Well, when I googled it, I found nothing. They all used the same formula, but I need to insert the `countif` function at a particular cell, may be at 300 or 500 - it depends in the variable value.

```
 Cells(count,"Q").formula = "=COUNTIF(cells($1,"P"):cells(count-1,"P"),cells(count,"P))=0"
```

Is this the way? Well, I tried in some ways but it's ending up higlighting the line with the red colour. How do I insert these formulae with a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
'case 1: if you know the destination range
Range("Q2").Formula = "=COUNTIF(P$1:P1,P2)=0"
Range("Q2").Copy Destination:=range("Q3:Q500")

'case 2: if the destination range is a variable
'minRow is a Long >= 1
Range("Q" & minRow + 1).Formula = "=COUNTIF(P$" & minRow & ":P" & minRow & ",P" & minRow + 1 & ")=0"
Range("Q" & minRow + 1).Copy Destination:=Range("Q" & minRow + 1 & ":Q" & maxRow)
```

Reference: [Issun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144757/how-do-i-insert-the-formula-into-the-cell-when-the-formula-keeps-changing-with-in/7145971#7145971) to Stack Overflow question *[How do I insert the formula into the cell when the formula keeps changing with increase in row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144757)*.

Comment: .Hey its not going to start from Q3 may be from Q300 I mean ,U have given for the end of the row where to end the copying but not for the start row I mean where to start .the starting row wont be always 3 might be 300 somtimes. Please update ur answer

Comment: @niko: this was an example, you could have adapted it by yourself. Anyway, i've edited my answer

Comment: but what about the countif The question was about countif not just destination!

Comment: @Issun thanks for helping me with your answers and I got one last issue about excel vba so Issun be ready for my last question on excel VBA if these question is solved then My project is finished ! thank god please answer my question.