# Selecting a range if column and rows are variables

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

This was my previous post [Insert COUNTIF formula when you have variable holding the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7172222/insert-countif-formula-when-you-have-variable-holding-the-value).

Below was the Solution.

```
Range("Q" & minRow + 1).Formula = "=COUNTIF(P$" & minRow & ":P" & minRow & ",P" & minRow + 1 & ")=0"
```

I have a new Question. What if the column is a variable?

What is the syntax if both are Variables (column and row are unknown and their values stored in a variable) and what is the syntax if column is variable and row is a number?

I have tried these ways

```
"=COUNTIF( & Columnz $1: & Columnz &2 ,& Columnz &2000)=0"
```

and these way

```
"=COUNTIF( "& Columnz" $1: " & Columnz"2,& Columnz &2000)=0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd like to add to the nice above responses, that OFFSET is very usefull, specially while looping.
e.g.:

```
With Range("B3")
    For i = 1 to 10
        .offset(0, i) = "something"
    Next i
End With
```

You can also make your VBA much more readable, and eliminate the need for "variable formulae" by using the native Excel (R1C1) syntax. Like

```
myRange.offset(0,i).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R1C[-1]:RC[-1])"
```

which means sum from row 1 of previous column till same row of previous column.

Finally, you can use the "dual arguments" version of RANGE(cell1, cell2):

```
With Range("B3")
    For i = 1 to 10
        .offset(0, i).formula = "=SUM(" & Range(cells(10, 1),cells(10, i)).address & ")"
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: *my 2 cents*: if you don't need the index inside the `for` loop, it is faster to use this kind of statement `For Each c In Range("A1:A10")` because then, Excel doesn't have to interpret the `Range` on every loop

Comment: @Jmax: very right. I concentrated on the question an d missed that view.

Answer (score 6):

To define a range, you can also use [`Cells`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139976%28v=office.10%29.aspx), for instance:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1)           '=Range ("A1")
ActiveSheet.Cells(1,"A")         '=Range ("A1")
```

If you want to define a range, you can do:

```
Range(Cells(1,1), Cells(10,5))   '=Range("A1:E10")
```

Thus, you can do:

```
'where Columnz is a Long or an Integer
"=COUNTIF(" & Range(Cells(1, Columnz), Cells(2, Columnz)).Address & "," & Cells(2000,Columnz).Address & ")=0"
```

Comment: +1 Yeah, I had only recently seen this as well. For some reason i had it in my mind that when you use Cells() that both values had to be numeric. :p

Answer (score 1):

The row number is already a variable in your example: `minRow`. String concatenation is done with an ampersand (`&`) in VB/A. You are halfway right but missing the second ampersand. You can think about it like this:

```
"first string" & variable1
```

This is a concat between 2 strings, if you want to add a third string, you have to use another ampersand:

```
"first string " & variable1 & "second string"
```

Your code:

```
 "=COUNTIF(" & columnz & "$"  & minRow & ":" & columnz & minRow & ",P" & (minRow + 1) & ")=0"
```

In response to your comments:

```
"=COUNTIF(" & columnz & "$1" & ":" & columnz & "1,P2)=0"
```

Just remove the variable from the string and include the row in the other string literals.

Comment: @Niko with number, do you mean a string literal (like: "1" or "2") or a numeric variable?

Comment: It shows application defined error Dont know why Can you please change The P column also to variable in your Answer thats where Im doing mistake I think

Answer (score 0):

it can be somthing like that:
startRow = 3
endRow = 17
myRange=("B" & StartRow & ":" & "B" & EndRow)
then your range = ("B3":"B17")