# Set variable columns between worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

Who wants easy points? I am trying to set a range of columns from one sheet to another using variables. `startm` will always be an integer. I know I can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12064731/excel-vba-select-a-dynamic-cell-range) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189978/syntax-in-selecting-a-range-if-column-and-rows-are-variables) but I hate `offset`XD Is there a "smarter" way besides concatenating a million "s and "&"s??

```
For Each s In thisWB.Worksheets
...
With ws
.Columns(3:14-startm+1)=s.columns(startm:14) 'this don't work ;_;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Set a range of columns from one sheet to another"? Like you want all of the values in one range to be copied to another range, where those two ranges are a group of columns?

Comment: Yea, exactly but I don't want formatting so not copy/pasting. Edit: I want to transfer columns 5 to 10 from one sheet to columns 2 to 7 in another sheet. Except those numbers will vary.

Comment: use `s.Columns(5).Resize(, 5).value = .Columns(2).Resize(, 5).value`

Comment: I am going the other way and it doesn't always start at 2 or 5 XD Edit: but I like your idea. I can do something like `.columns(startm+1).resize(startm)` etc

Comment: Fair enough what about `.Columns(3).Resize(, 14 - startm + 1).value = s.Columns(startm).Resize(, 14 - startm + 1).value`

Comment: Why not post as answer and get easy points =P Resize is kinda similar to offset though but I guess it's most "efficient" and "obvious" to see what's going on at a quick glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, I would use:

```
.Columns(3).Resize(, 14 - startm + 1).value = s.Columns(startm).Resize(, 14 - startm + 1).value
```

Comment: To make this one more "immediately obvious" you could stick `14-startm + 1` into a variable with a nice name like `writeColumn` and ditto for your `readColumn`. Then the next poor schmuck that comes along and has to decipher what was written will know what's going on without the burden of having to think.

Comment: +1 just for poor schmuck. Yes and no. I personally hate deciphering variables and that would just add one more even if I agree it makes sense. Yea, I am demented XD

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working with column numbers instead of letters, the best approach here is a `for` loop:

```
For Each s In thisWB.Worksheets
...
With ws

    For col = 3 to 14-startm+1
        'may have to adjust these values in here to fit your dynamic need, but
        '  the overall idea here is sound
        .Columns(col).Value = s.Columns(col+startm).Value
    Next col
End ws
Next s
```

I didn't reverse engineer your startm +/- stuff here on backhalf of that `.columns()...` line, but this should do what you need after filling in that blank.

Comment: Sigh. Overkill isn't it? I guess I am looking for a "smart" way.

Comment: Welcome to VBA and Excel. Just stick `On Error Resume Next` at the start of your subroutine and write whatever you want.

Comment: You'd think msft would build it so one can write `columns(x:y)` and have it work but nooooooooooooooooo XD

Comment: YEa.. I don't get it either. Referring to columns and ranges as letters in your programming environment. Not the most genius thing MS has ever done.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
Range(.Cells(1, 3), .Cells(1, 14 - startm + 1)).EntireColumn = _
   Range(Sheets(1).Cells(1, startm), Sheets(1).Cells(1, 14)).EntireColumn.Value
```

But without certain limitations, it could be slow

Comment: Yea that looks so hedious -_- I guess I want something that's immediately obvious that I am going from column x to column y XD