# Loop sheets and transfer data

Tags: excel, vba

My brain is fried and this is easy points for the usual suspects. `div` is an array holding sheet names. I am looping through sheets in a master book and if one of the master sheets match one of the sheets in the `div` array, I want to transfer some data from master sheet to a sheet in `thisworkbook`.

In the event the sheet does not exist in `thisworkbook`, add one and name it after the master sheet. What's the most efficient way to do this? I feel like nested loops is a bad idea -_- A collection perhaps?

```
For i = 0 To UBound(div())

    For Each s In book.Worksheets

        wsName = Left(s.Name, 5)

        If div(i) = wsName Then
        If wsExists(wsName) Then
            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName)
            Exit For
            'Debug.Print "true " & ws.name
        Else
            Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
            ws.Name = Left(s.Name, 5)
            'Debug.Print "false " & ws.name
        End If
        end if
    Next

    With ws
    .Columns(Start).Resize(, 2).Value = s.Columns("A:B").Value
    .Columns(Start + label).Resize(, cols).Value = s.Columns(Start + label).Resize(, cols).Value
    End With

Next
```

Do I even need to check if sheet exists? Code stolen from [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688131/test-or-check-if-sheet-exists/6688482#comment54125381_6688482).

```
Function wsExists(sName As String) As Boolean
Dim sht As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sName)
On Error GoTo 0
wsExists = Not sht Is Nothing

End Function
```

Edit: I am calling the loop from a separate routine.

```
Call drop(thisWB, thisRange, ccArr)
```

where `ccArr` is

```
Dim ccArr() As Variant
ccArr = Array("30500", "30510", "30515", "30530", "30600", "30900", "40500")
```

The routine where above loop resides opens with

```
Sub drop(book As Workbook, cols As Integer, div As Variant, Optional startCol As Integer)
```

but I am getting a `byref` error trying to pass the array ;_;

Comment: What will happen if you don't check for it's existence?  Will it error with some sort of "sheet with that name already exists.  You could just handle the error.  But there should be no reason you can't just check for it.

Comment: Should be efficient if your number of sheets is reasonable.  Would put a few test together with example but I have to run.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what percentage of the time (roughly) would an element of `div` not match an existing sheet name?

Comment: Excellent question. Thisworkbook is actually barren to begin. BUT I will run it again with a second master book where 90%+ of the sheets will match. Edit: the two master books hold 300+ sheets. The array will never hold more than, say 30ish. Edit2: I realize I could do this far more intelligently but I can't ask broad questions on SO =P

Comment: change `div As Variant` to `div() as Variant` in your `Sub drop`. You can also change `Dim ccArr() as Variant` to `Dim ccArr() as String` then change your argument in `drop` to `div() as String` as well.

Comment: A slightly different question... will it ever happen that 100% of the elements in `div` will match existing sheets when your proc runs?

Comment: Hmmm reluctant to commit to 100% but yes it's possible. I guess I would know after I run the macro XD

Comment: ah ... its because you div(i) is variant type and the function requires a string ... you can change `div(i) to string` or maybe `Cstr(div(i))` will work (not tested)

Comment: lol Scott. It worked but you killed part of my code and didn't replace it =P Getting object error on `s.Columns("A:B").Value`. You killed `s` which was the sheet of masterbook =P Edit: wait, I dont wanna pass thisworkbook. I want master XD Edit2: wait, maybe not... brain toooooo fried ;_;

Comment: I think I may have solved that, too ... see my edited answer ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nested loop is superfluous. You can check the sheet name from `div` directly against the workbook you want to check it against, then add it if needed.

See the code below, which also addresses the concerns in the edits to your OP. I modified the `wsExists` function to include a set reference to a particular workbook, which I think makes it more dynamic.

```
'assumes thisWB  and thisRange set above

Dim ccArr() As String, sList As String
sList = "30500,30510,30515,30530,30600,30900,40500"
ccArr = Split(sList, ",")

drop thisWB, thisRange, ccArr 'assumes thisWb and thisRange are set already

' rest of code
'==================================================

Sub drop(book As Workbook, cols As Integer, div() As String, Optional startCol as Integer)

For i = 0 To UBound(div())

    If wsExists(ThisWorkbook, div(i)) Then
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(div(i))
        Exit For
        'Debug.Print "true " & ws.name
    Else
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
        ws.Name = div(i)
    End If

    'i think you need this here, otherwise, it will only work on the last worksheet in your loop
    With ws
        Dim s As Worksheet
        Set s = book.Sheets(div(i))
        .Columns(Start).Resize(, 2).Value = s.Columns("A:B").Value
        .Columns(Start + Label).Resize(, cols).Value = s.Columns(Start + Label).Resize(, cols).Value
    End With

Next

End Sub

Function wsExists(wb As Workbook, sName As String) As Boolean
Dim sht As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next
Set sht = wb.Sheets(sName)
On Error GoTo 0
wsExists = Not sht Is Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: I think I need to change `s.Columns("A:B").Value` to `book.Worksheets(wsName).Columns("A:B").Value` yes?

Comment: Downvoted and flagged. Edit: you also killed the `left`. I was not supposed to think. I expect turnkey answers. Gonna ask for you to get banned from SO.

Comment: lolol I kid =P Upvoted. Question, it works but it's slow? Edit: ooo you set `s`. Guess that works too. Edit2: actually, still no `left` so still fail =P No big deal. More importantly, the `split` forces a string I guess?

Comment: bizarre joke - that through me through a loop (no pun intended) as I was just reading a thread about a less than helpful person on SO ...  Anyway, I killed the left because it didn't seem to be needed if you were only use div() to get the sheet name. Do you need it? And you say slow  ... please define?

Comment: oops lol I joke too much XD You can ask @macroman ^_^; I will refrain from going forward. The master book sheets have extra chars that don't match array. Not big deal. I fixed that. Well, array had 7 sheets? Took maybe 30 secs to run. Feels slow. Could be the `resize` perhaps and not the loop?

Comment: Also just realized what happens if array has a sheet not in master. Unlikely but possible.... sigh headache -_-

Comment: it could be the column resizing ... You can test that by commenting out that code and seeing how long it takes to run without those lines.

Comment: lolololol instantaneously. So what's better than resize.... I asked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33153910/set-variable-columns-between-worksheets) yesterday XD Edit: well, that's another question. Thank you for the help ^_^

Comment: i'll look into that question for you and see if I can help.

Comment: first thing is that pasting entire columns can be **very** slow and is usually not necessary (because there are usually many blank rows at the bottom - i.e - are you really using all 1,048,576 rows? ...  If you can find the last used row of data you can limit your statement to only set the values for the columns and rows you actually need. If you want help with this, post another question to make it easier to work with.

Comment: yes, I meant to say setting, not pasting ... either way, working with entire column can be **very** slow, as I mentioned. reducing it to only the rows you need will most likely speed it up to ~instantaneous.

Comment: Please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33179390/quicker-alternative-to-resize)

Comment: @findwindow: you deleted your question related to re-sizing and I was going to provide some details - I'll place the info in a new answer here, just as a reference

Answer (score 1):

Related to the re-sizing code:

This statement `ws.Columns(1).Resize(, 2)` translates to "2 million+ rows from column 1 and 2"

The solution you found works well but it's not dynamic (hard-coded last row)

This is how I'd setup the copy of columns:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub copyCols()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    Dim cols As Long, lr As Long

    Dim col1 As Long    'renamed from "Start" (VBA keyword - property)
    Dim lbl As Long     'renamed from "label" (VBA keyword - Control object)

    Set ws1 = Sheet1    'ws
    Set ws2 = Sheet2    'book.Worksheets(wsName & "-F")

    col1 = 1
    cols = 2
    lbl = 1

    lr = ws2.Cells(ws2.UsedRange.Row + ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng1 = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, col1), ws1.Cells(lr, col1 + 1))
    Set rng2 = ws2.Range("A1:B" & lr)

    rng1.Value2 = rng2.Value2

    Set rng1 = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, col1 + lbl), ws1.Cells(lr, col1 + lbl + cols))
    Set rng2 = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(1, col1 + lbl), ws2.Cells(lr, col1 + lbl + cols))

    rng1.Value2 = rng2.Value2 
End Sub
```

Comment: Let me know if I should delete this

Comment: I shouldn't have deleted that question. This is an amazing answer.

Comment: I'm glad it helped and I think others should be aware of how tricky default parameters can get. I think you can undelete it if you want but I'm not sure

Comment: nice ! I copied the answer there as well