# Quicker alternative to `resize`?

Tags: excel, vba

Per @ScottHoltzman's suggestion. I am setting certain columns from one book to another book. `resize` is proving to be very slow. What's a quicker method? I probably only need 200 rows max from each column.

```
With ws
        .Columns(Start).Resize(, 2).Value = book.Worksheets(wsName & "-F").Columns("A:B").Value
        .Columns(Start + label).Resize(, cols).Value = book.Worksheets(wsName & "-F").Columns(Start + label).Resize(, cols).Value
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement `ws.Columns(1).Resize(, 2)` translates to "2 million+ rows from column 1 and 2"

The solution you found works well but it's not dynamic (hard-coded last row)

This is how I'd setup the copy of columns:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub copyCols()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
    Dim cols As Long, lr As Long

    Dim col1 As Long    'renamed from "Start" (VBA keyword - property)
    Dim lbl As Long     'renamed from "label" (VBA keyword - Control object)

    Set ws1 = Sheet1    'ws
    Set ws2 = Sheet2    'book.Worksheets(wsName & "-F")

    col1 = 1
    cols = 2
    lbl = 1

    lr = ws2.Cells(ws2.UsedRange.Row + ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng1 = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, col1), ws1.Cells(lr, col1 + 1))
    Set rng2 = ws2.Range("A1:B" & lr)

    rng1.Value2 = rng2.Value2

    Set rng1 = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(1, col1 + lbl), ws1.Cells(lr, col1 + lbl + cols))
    Set rng2 = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(1, col1 + lbl), ws2.Cells(lr, col1 + lbl + cols))

    rng1.Value2 = rng2.Value2 
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you concatenate ranges? `set rng1=Range(ws1.Cells(1, col1), ws1.Cells(lr, col1 + 1)) & Range(ws1.Cells(1, x), ws1.Cells(lr, x+ 1))`? Perhaps a `union` in front?

Comment: Sure, but try to avoid `Union` if possible because it does a lot of work behind the scenes (checking every cell in every range to be combined to see if any rows or columns overlap; the same with `Intersect()`). `Union` is most convenient when the ranges (columns) are not adjacent like column 1, 3, 20, 35. But if they're in the same area use the faster standard notation like `A1:C200`. I'd use `Union` for something like this `Set rng = Union(Range("A1:C200"), Range("E1:E200"), Range("H1:I200"))` (I'd replace 200 with a variable holding the last row in UsedRange)

Comment: Scrapped the union idea. It wasn't working :/ Just set two ranges instead XD